# In EF Core with Web API, does an entity class replace the need for a model class?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to learn how to build an API using EF Core. I'm building a Paycheck API and I have an entity class for Paycheck type that looks like this:

```
[Table("PaycheckType")]
public class PaycheckTypeEntity
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    [Column("Id", Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    [Column("Type", Order = 1)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [Column("CustomSortOrder", Order = 2)]
    public int CustomSortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

When using EF Core with Web API, does an entity class like this replace the need for a model class like the one below?

```
public class PaycheckType
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
   public int CustomSortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will not be a perfect answer for this and mostly it depends on type of project. Mostly it is nice if both class is different.

1. Your API is like business layer and so it may possible that it receive and process complex model that span across multiple table.
2. One example is like that , At DB level your entity has certain property that manage by DB and you don't want to expose to API so if you create API then it create problem.
3. Also mixing those will create problem for EF core for few cases to track the entity clearly.  Also complexity get increase when you have navigation property then it is problem.
4. Another case is like when you expose data from multiple table but for API it is single model. This is to provide data from API as well as accept data in API.
5. We should keep responsibility for each layer.